# Undefined Parameters Error

Tags: python, parameters, undefined

I have two functions and am trying to call a value from the first in the second. Even though I have passed the parameter containing the value into the second function I still keep getting the error name `'dm_p' is not defined`. 
I have tried re-defining it in the second function and passing the parameters but nothing has helped.

My code is:

```
def run(detvar, dmvar='CDM'):
    dm_p = DM(dmvar['density'], dmvar['velocity'], dmvar['mass'], dmvar['cross_section'])
    elif dmvar == 'CDM':
        dm_p = DM(0.3, 230., 10., 1e-5)

def calcrate_1(dm_p):
    rate_1 = dm_p.cross_section*v_esc*(dm_p.density/dm_p.mass)*(ap.constants.N_A/det.atomic_mass)*det.mass_of_detector
    return rate_1
    print("RATE 1: ", rate_1)
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Comment: Thanks Morgan. The indentation didn't carry when I copied my code and I didn't realise.

Comment: You have an elif statement without having an if statement to start the block.  You also have scope issues.  In order for calcrate to use dm_p you need to return it from the run function and call calcrate with that variable.

Comment: Hi Wombat, my if statement is in another higher section of code, so my elif statement is working. Even when I "return dm_p" in my run function I am still unable to pass or call dm_p in my second function. It still is giving me the 'dm_p is undefined' error message.

Comment: Post the entire function

Comment: "quite large" is relative. If it's less than 200 lines then it's perfectly reasonable to post here... well, I say that, but it's only reasonable if it's *necessary*. You need to start with the code that you have and then gradually pare it down until you're left with the code that exhibits the error.